# What kind of application is more suited to create as desktop rather than online application?

Tags: desktop-application

any idea anyone?

Answer (score 14):

A web browser.

Answer (score 5):

Applications with large memory, local data, or intensive cpu requirements:

- Compilers
- Ray Tracing Programs
- Multimedia Applications

Applicaitons involving sensitive data:

- Payrol Software
- Inventory Systems
- Customer Databases Systems

Programs Interacting with Hardware

- Medical Callibration Systems
- Call Center Applications
- Builing Alarm Monitoring/Climate Control/Video Survailance Systems
- RFID Systems

Critical Uptime Solutions

- 911 Emergency Dispatch Systems
- Access Control to Sensitive Areas
- Monitoring solutions for critical servers

Answer (score 3):

I would say applications that require very little latency between computation and representation (such as games or video editing). Other applications that require interfacing with local hardware are not well suited for online applications.

Almost any answer you get will depend on the fact that your network connection is the bottleneck. Keep in mind, though, that when you are dealing with online applications, most all of what you are doing is going to be pipelined through the network connection. Even frameworks that are offloading a lot of computation to the local CPU will still be pipelining the framework itself through the network connection. If that connection is slow, lagging, or unreliable, then so is your application.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, things that need to access large, local files. Video/image/sound editing, games, 3d modeling programs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would say anything that has to communicate with specific hardware. Also programs with performance requirments (eg. games, sure, in theory you could run games in a browser too (eg. Quake Live), but that's nothing compared to Crysis :D ).

Answer (score 2):

iTunes - unless apple wants to host 80 terabytes of pirated music